# How can I find which Log analytics table is supported by which resource/solution?

Tags: azure

How can I find which Log analytics table is supported by which resource/solution? I need to work on log tables and need to find out which I need to support depending on solution or resources.

I am not finding any consolidated information on same. If I try to check a table the I can see supported solution or resources for that particular table.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/tables-resourcetype ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Supported Resources and solutions in the Log Analytics workspace by following the below steps:-

I agree with **Jul_DW** AFAIK you can find the consolidated list of all the Log analytics tables in this MS document as there’s no other document with the list of logs and check the same for the category type in the left Filter by title:-
[Azure Monitor table reference index by resource type | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/tables-resourcetype)

You can also make use of Rest API to call the Log analytics workspace and List all the tables in the LA workspace with its resources like below:-

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceName}/tables?api-version=2021-12-01-preview
```

Output:-

[image]

[image]

List Data sources by filtering specific table:-

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000/resourcegroups/OIAutoRest5123/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/AzTest9724/dataSources?$filter=kind='WindowsEvent'&api-version=2020-08-01
```

[image]

**References:-**

[Tables - List By Workspace - REST API (Azure Log Analytics) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/tables/list-by-workspace?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)

[Data Sources - List By Workspace - REST API (Azure Log Analytics) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/data-sources/list-by-workspace?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0)